# Ошибка при парсинге сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Когда пытаюсь спарсить класс, возвращает "none"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



url = ('https://prnt.sc/iewkgj')
responce = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
element1 = soup.find('div', class_ = 'top-grundik')
print(element1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://prnt.sc/iewkgj'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
element1 = soup.find('div', class_ = 'top-grundik')

print(element1)
```

Выведет:

```
<div class="top-grundik" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom: 0px;"> <div class="grundik-div grundik-970"> <style>div.grundik-970{width:970px !important;}div.top-grundik-report-970{display: none;}</style>
<ins data-a4g-block="" data-a4g-blockcampaign="" data-a4g-zone="60918"></ins><script type="text/javascript">(function (cdnPath, charset) {var el = document.createElement('SCRIPT'),body = document.body,asyncAjsSrc = cdnPath + '/async-ajs.min.js',isAsyncPresent = (function (scripts, asyncAjsSrc) {for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {if (scripts[i].src === asyncAjsSrc) {return true;}}return false;} (document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT'), asyncAjsSrc));if (!isAsyncPresent) {el.type = 'text/javascript';el.async = true;el.src = asyncAjsSrc;if (charset) {el.setAttribute('data-a4g-charset', charset);}body.appendChild(el);}} (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https://cdn.ad4game.com' : 'http://cdn.ad4game.com', ''));</script> <div class="top-grundik-report top-grundik-report-970"> <a class="js-report-misleadin-grundik" href="#">Report misleading ad</a> </div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!!! Просто нужно было добавить заголовки???

Comment: без user-agent сайт возвращал 503 и никакого top-grundik там не было... по-умолчанию requests отпарвляет что-то типа 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1'